# NodeJS + Tampermonkey can they work together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tampermonkey

I am creating software that helps me and my colleagues to work on tickets at work, as our current software is really bad. At this moment I am using program that I wrote in Tampermonkey, it is giving information about queue and all other fancy stuff. But I reached limit of that, as website is a limitation, so I started to create website that could do much more, yet I am not sure how to connect it as when I am using Tampermonkey to create overlay with all needed data. My idea was to: 1) Gather all data by tampermonkey and send it to nodejs server. Node would keep array (that's all I need) locally and then I would be able to access it.

Is this possible, is this a correct approach? Unfortunately I am limited by options that I can use by company security policy.

Comment: If your nodejs app exposes a web server API on a standard http port, you can post the data there using GM_xmlhttpRequest in your userscript.

Comment: thanks, will try that